# npm start error - No production canister_ids.json found. Continuing with local

Tags: npm, webpack, webpack-dev-server, npm-start

Whenever I run npm start the same "error" message appears "No production canister_ids.json found. Continuing with local"

At first there seemed to be a proxy problem, detectable in the browser console. I managed to solve it by editing the proxy in webpack.config.js

However, the error on npm start continues.
I've already tried changing the versions of npm, webpack, webpack-dev-server, dotenv-webpack and editing the "start" in "package.json", but it doesn't work.

Can anyone recommend another solution?
Or how to identify exactly what the problem is?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rWml7.jpg)

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Updating webpack version to 4.10.0 in the package.json and running npm install fixed the issue.

Related issue from webpack repo: webpack/webpack#15951

Answer (score 0):

After all, it's just a warning that appears because I haven't deployed to the network yet :D

Thanks to Kyle Peacock for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try running:

```
npm install webpack-cli@4.10.0 --save-dev
```

After changing `"webpack-cli": "^4.9.0"` to `"webpack-cli": "^4.10.0"` in the `package-lock.json` file.